# Rule engine in .NET

Tags: rules-engine

I have to import data from Excel to an SQL database. The Excel data contains various parameters and their values, like P1, P1, P4, P5, etc. I have to apply business rules. Like *if (P1 > 100 and P1 < 200) then insert the record in database*. Similarly, in some cases, string values are also validated. Can I have any open source rule engine that contains UI to change, add, and delete the rules? I am using C# to read the Excel data and and inserting the records.

One more thing, which of the following is the best approach?

- Read Excel data first and store every record as an object in a collection, iterate through the collection, apply business rules on every object and insert record in the database. Or
- Read one record from Excel, apply business rules and insert the record in the database. Repeat the process for the whole Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution so users can manage the rules?

Comment: Yes Preferably! but most important is rules should be stored in some repository even if i don't have UI for ends user to change them.

Comment: Check the WF .NET Rule Engine or check out [RuleProof](http://www.solvono.com/Products/RuleProof.aspx) from Solvono.

Answer (score 5):

You may look for different simple rule engines in .NET. However, in the case if you're using .NET 3.0 or later, you [can use the Rules Engine of Windows Workflow Foundation](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/08/09/WF-Rules-Engine-without-Workflow.aspx) **without** using actually Workflow.

We have done this in our project, and you are free to use SQL or XML as the back-end, and it works pretty good. You can use the IDE that comes with the Workflow examples and use that in your own application.

You may also consider the following options:

- [Open Source Rule Engines in C#](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/rule-engines)
- [Simple Rule Engine from SourceForge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdsre/)